# How can I control views visibility (visible/invisible) with orientation change?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I want to design layouts like this:

**Portrait mode xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ToolBar>
    <ToolBar>
    <TextView>
    </TextView>
    <VideoView>
    <VideoView>
    <Webview>
    </Webview>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Landscape mode xml:**

```
 <RelativeLayout>
    <VideoView>
    <VideoView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Other views will be invisible for landscape mode. Thanks in advance. I am novice in android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your layout contains videoview I think you wnt to play video on this page.

To prevent activity recreation and video restarts you should add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to activity declaration and than manage layout in `onConfigurationChanged`

Just find views in ``` onCreate`` than show hide them in ```onConfigurationChanged```

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // setContentView and another onCreate logic code

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    textview = findViewById(R.id.textview);
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoview);

    updateLayout(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    updateLayout(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}

private void updateLayout(boolean isLandscape) {  
    if (isLandscape) {
        textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        webview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    } else {
        textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getSupportActionBar().show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks . It working perfect. you save all most 2 days .@Pogonets Antom

Answer (score 0):

You can create two different layout xml file for the two different orientations with same name and store the file for portrait mode in the **`layout`** directory and landscape version in the **`layout-land`** directory under `res` directory. *I think it's better to do it this way than managing visibility in runtime*

Comment: This will break video playback on rotation

Comment: @PogonetsAnton Sorry, I didn't played with the `VideoView`. If it break's then its better go with your answer.

Comment: Sorry. My videoview working perfect with @Pogonets Antom answer.

Comment: @AslamHossin Thats great, I am really happy to hear that. Happy coding friend. Also give him a vote

Comment: How to setLayoutParams of video view. for Portrait mode:  videoView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200)); and for Landscape mode :   videoView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); now working. please help or suggestion.